# How do read a SEC txt-file into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import, error-handling

I am trying to use SEC (U.S. Security and Exchange Commision data). The [SEC provides useful data in a `txt`format](https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets.html). I am using 
Financial Statement Data Sets for the second quarter of 2017. You can find the data I use [here](https://www.sec.gov/files/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets/2017q2.zip).

I try to read the `txt`files into a `pandas dataframe`. I tried it the following ways:

```
sub = pd.read_fwf('sub.txt')
sub_1 = pd.read_csv('sub.txt')
```

I get no error with using Pandas' `read_fwf` function - but the output is utter rubbish. Here is the head of the dataframe:

```
adsh cik name sic countryba stprba cityba zipba bas1 bas2 baph countryma stprma cityma zipma mas1 mas2 countryinc stprinc ein former changed afs wksi fye form period fy fp filed accepted prevrpt detail instance nciks aciks  Unnamed: 1
0   0000002178-17-000038\t2178\tADAMS RESOURCES & ...   NaN
1   0000002488-17-000107\t2488\tADVANCED MICRO DEV...   NaN
```

I do get an error when using `read_csv`: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 7, saw 3`

Any ideas on how tor read the data into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the files are tab separated - that's why you're seeing `\t` in the results. `pandas` `read_csv` defaults to comma separated values, so you have to change the separator. This is controlled by the `sep` parameter. In addition, you will need to provide the proper encoding (errors are thrown when trying to read the `num`, `pre`, and `tag` files). Generally `ISO-8859-1` is a good choice.

```
#import pandas
import pandas as pd

#read in the .txt file and choose a separator and encoding standard
df = pd.read_csv('sub.txt', sep='\t', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

#output the results
print(df)

                     adsh      cik                                   name  \
0     0000002178-17-000038     2178         ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY, INC.   
1     0000002488-17-000107     2488             ADVANCED MICRO DEVICES INC   
2     0000002969-17-000019     2969      AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC /DE/   
3     0000002969-17-000024     2969      AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC /DE/   
4     0000003499-17-000010     3499                         ALEXANDERS INC   
5     0000003545-17-000043     3545                              ALICO INC   
6     0000003570-17-000073     3570                    CHENIERE ENERGY INC
```